# Can you give a C# member the attributes of another member in a different class?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Let's say we have a situation where we have two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and these both have the method `DoSomething()`. `ClassB` contains a `ClassA` as a field, and when `ClassB.DoSomething()` is called it delegates the call to `ClassA.DoSomething()`. Also, `ClassA.DoSomething()` has some attribute on it. So we have something like

```
class ClassA {
    [SomeAttribute]
    int DoSomething() { return 0; }
}

class ClassB {
    public ClassA CA { get; }
    int DoSomething() { return CA.DoSomething(); }
}
```

My question is, is there some way of applying the attributes that exist on `ClassA.DoSomething()` to `ClassB.DoSomething()` without repeating that code? What if `ClassA.DoSomething()` has multiple attributes? Is there some attribute that might look like `[ApplyAttributes(typeof(ClassA), "DoSomething")]` ?

I'm not looking at applying attributes dynamically at runtime, this could all happen at compile time.

This is for a Silverlight solution, so certain reflection techniques such as TypeDescriptors are unavailable to me.

Comment: Is there any relationship between classA and classB?

Comment: Just the association from ClassB to ClassA

Answer (score 2):

I would create a custom [**TypeDescriptor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) that would be responsible for analyzing your ApplyAttributes attribute and returning relevant attributes at run-time.

I think it would be easier to do than some nasty build step that will modify your source-code before compilation.

Comment: +1 but `TypeDescriptor` is a static sealed class. I think you meant to say "implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`", which is an interface detected and used by `TypeDescriptor` if present on an object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx

Comment: This looks to be what I'm after, thanks a lot (and to you for the clarification Wim). I'll let you know how I get along.

Comment: I took a look into this approach but my application is in Silverlight and it looks like TypeDescriptor and ICustomTypeDescriptor are not available in Silverlight, so I'm going to mark this as not answered. Thanks anyway, they certainly look like something interesting to look into in any case.

Comment: @Martin - you might want to update your question - it doesn't say anywhere that the solution is for Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are a run time thing. That is knowing what attributes are applied to a class requires a live instance of a class.

Now if/when Microsoft provides the "Compiler as a Service" capability then you may be able to get this information at "compile" time and do something with it. Essentially, unless you parse your code file and modify the C# code of the other classes there is no way to do what you're looking to do at compile time.

If your classes are related by inheritance, then you can define your attributes to be inheritable.